# cURL file upload not working in PHP 5.6.x running on Windows 2012 R2

Tags: php, curl

I am using the following code to upload a file to a server using a .NET upload script:

```html
    if(isset($_FILES['fileToUpload'])) {
        $url = "path/to/FileUpload.aspx";  // request URL
        $filename = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'];
        $filedata = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'];
        $filesize = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['size'];
        $filetype = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['type'];
        
        if ($filedata != '') {
            
            $dom = dom_import_simplexml($response);
            $processXML = $dom->ownerDocument->saveXML($dom->ownerDocument->documentElement);
            
            $params = $companyId.",".$userId.",".$dataXML;
            $headers = array("Content-Type:multipart/form-data"); // cURL headers for file uploading
            
            $ch = curl_init();
            
            $file = new CURLFile($filedata,$filetype,$filename);
            
            $postfields = array("file" => $file,"params" => $params);
            
            $options = array(
                CURLOPT_URL => $url,
                CURLOPT_PORT => 8085,
                CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
                CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
                CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD => false,
                CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
                CURLOPT_POST => 1,
                CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
                CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postfields,
                CURLOPT_INFILESIZE => $filesize,
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
            ); // cURL options
            
            curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
            $result = curl_exec($ch);
            
            $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
            
            $http_code = $info['http_code'];
            
            if(!curl_errno($ch)) {
                if ($http_code == 200) {
                    
                    echo "File uploaded successfully<br>";
                    
                    // If file uploaded successfully, post the question...
                    postQuestion($arg1,$arg2);
                    
                } else {
                    $arr = array('status' => 'error', 'message' => 'http error');
                }
            } else {
                $arr = array('status' => 'error', 'message' => 'upload error');
                echo json_encode($arr);
            }
            
            curl_close($ch);
        } else {
            echo "Invalid file";
        }
    }
```

**PROBLEM**

The script always returns `array('status' => 'error', 'message' => 'upload error');`

This same code works in Apache (xampp).

I checked all configs (php.ini, required .dll's) on the server and everything seems to be in order.

Some posts here and elsewhere suggested copying `ssleay.dll` and `libeay.dll` from PHP installation directory to `Windows\System32`. Tried that as well.

`curl_error($ch)` returns nothing

`curl_errno($ch)` returns 43

**Environment Details**

- Windows 2012 R2
- PHP v5.6.0
- cURL v7.36.0

What am I missing here? I just started learning PHP 2 weeks back, so please be gentle :)

Comment: Windows 2012 R2? so `IIS`? Did you check the event logs? Most likely a permission issue.

Comment: Yes, IIS. It does seem to be a permission issue-  so could you guide me where to check the event logs? However, there are other perfectly functioning code for uploading using the same `.aspx` file, _albeit in .NET and working on the same port_.

Comment: Open IIS Manager->click site under connections-> click icon that says `Logging`, look at the path to the log file.

Comment: Ok, will check and update.

Comment: Looked at the logs, don't see anything unusual. Anything specific I should be looking for?